# How do I reinstall default fonts?

Tags: 10.10, fonts

i have deleted the default fonts in Ubuntu Desktop 10.10. IE, arial, verdana, etc. Does anyone know how I can get them back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the msttcorefonts package.

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I was able to answer my own question with a bit of guided research. You need the package: `msttcorefonts`

Or command line instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

This link explains in detail how to reinstall core fonts:

- [Reference](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/09/installing-microsoft-fonts/)