# What packages do I need to compile .tex documents using XeLaTeX?

Tags: 10.04, fonts, latex

I'm aware of the existence of similar threads on this forum. But any of replies mach to my problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 and I hadn't problems with fonts till I've decided to use XeLaTeX instead of LaTeX (cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/typesetting-a-document-using-arabic-script/12358#12358). The problem is that I'm not able to compile any .tex document using XeLaTeX, as well as properly display XeLaTeX documentation. As I've learn thanks to mentioned thread, XeLaTeX uses the fonts availables in general in the system.

I was trying yo read `fontspec` documentation, but it opens in pdf with a lot of white gaps and terminal output (quite long) consist mostly of errors. This are just few lines of it:

```
Error: Missing language pack for 'Adobe-Japan1' mapping 
Error: Unknown font tag 'F5.1' 
Error (24124): No font in show 
Error: Unknown font tag 'F5.1'
```

I was trying to compile simple XeLaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

Hello World!
\end{document}
```

without succes. This is terminal output of compilation:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ex.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, polish, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
fontspec.cfg loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))kpathsea: Invalid fontname `Linux Libertine O', contains ' '

! Font \zf@basefont="Linux Libertine O" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) fi
le or installed font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.3 \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

?
```

I can't find `Linux Libertine O`. Searching for `otf-` by `aptitude` gives as result:

```
maria@maria-laptop:/etc/fonts$ aptitude search otf
p   emdebian-rootfs                                                             - emdebian root filesystem support                                                      
p   libotf-bin                                                                  - A Library for handling OpenType Font - utilities                                      
p   libotf-dev                                                                  - A Library for handling OpenType Font - development                                    
i   libotf0                                                                     - A Library for handling OpenType Font - runtime                                        
p   libotf0-dbg                                                                 - The libotf libraries and debugging symbols                                            
p   libpam-dotfile                                                              - A PAM module which allows users to have more than one password                        
p   livecd-rootfs                                                               - construction script for the livecd rootfs                                             
p   makebootfat                                                                 - Utility to create a bootable FAT filesystem                                           
p   otf-ipaexfont                                                               - Japanese OpenType font, IPAexFont (IPAexGothic/Mincho)                                
p   otf-ipaexfont-gothic                                                        - Japanese OpenType font, IPAexFont (IPAexGothic)                                       
p   otf-ipaexfont-mincho                                                        - Japanese OpenType font, IPAexFont (IPAexMincho)                                       
p   otf-ipafont                                                                 - Japanese OpenType font set, IPAfont                                                   
p   otf-ipafont-gothic                                                          - Japanese OpenType font set, IPA Gothic font                                           
p   otf-ipafont-mincho                                                          - Japanese OpenType font set, IPA Mincho font                                           
p   otf-stix                                                                    - the Scientific and Technical Information eXchange fonts                               
p   otf-thai-tlwg                                                               - Thai fonts in OpenType format                                                         
p   otf-yozvox-yozfont                                                          - Japanese proportional Handwriting OpenType font                                       
p   otf2bdf                                                                     - generate BDF bitmap fonts from OpenType outline fonts                                 
p   robotfindskitten                                                            - Zen Simulation of robot finding kitten
```

So font in question is not just uninstalled, but not available, if I'm not wrong. Does it mean that I lack some repositoires?

I was trying also to apply solution from the thread [How do I reinstall default fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24983/how-do-i-reinstall-default-fonts), but the result is:

```
maria@maria-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
[sudo] password for maria: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting ttf-mscorefonts-installer instead of msttcorefonts
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
maria@maria-laptop:~$
```

It seems that is not a usual problem for use of XeLaTeX; nobody in the mentioned thread suggested instalation of anything else than TeX Live.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've managed to solve the problem.

1. Lacking fonts were accessible via Ubuntu Software Center (I thought before that it's just another graphical presentation of the same mechanism as `apt` and Synaptic...)
2. Problem with documentation solved by installation of `poppler-data`.

Hope it helps to somebody with similar problem.

Comment: Good job sorting this out, can you reword the title to be something more descriptive than "font on ubuntu 10.04?" so it's a bit more detailed? Thanks!

Comment: @Jorge I could reword the title if I knew what formulation would be more accurate... I'm not fluent in English and not very skilled for informatics... Any hints?

Comment: No clue either, I barely understand the subject you're talking about myself, I'll give it a go though.