# After system crash all characters are substituted by rectangles

Tags: gnome, fonts

After a system crash and therefore a reboot all characters got substituted by white rectangles (only these rectangles are displayed by 12.04 LTS - even in the terminal).

The characters in e.g. Google Chrome are correctly displayed. When I start a terminal session via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, the system characters are properly shown.

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Were you using the default system fonts? If yes, try the [answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/25008/12864) and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading `gnome-tweak-tool` and changing system's default font OR re-install the system's default font.

**Re-installing Default fonts:**

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

**Changing default fonts:**

Install `gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

You should be able to change the system wide fonts from the `Fonts` tab.

[image]