# Reinstall all default fonts

Tags: fonts

I tried to remove non-western fonts (a lot of Noto stuff) but I ended up removing too many fonts.
I want to do a sort of "restore to factory settings".
I already tried with `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` but it's already installed.

I think I could probably launch `apt install` followed by a list of fonts but to do that I need a **list of fonts installed by default in Ubuntu** but I haven't found it yet. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: "mscorefonts" is not exactly "factory default".

Comment: sorry, I assumed they were based on this other question https://askubuntu.com/questions/24983/how-do-i-reinstall-default-fonts

Comment: See my answer in the mean time on how to see which fonts are default, and eventually reinstall everything that default automatically.

Comment: `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` installs the Microsoft fonts *when it's installed*. If they've gone missing, you'll need to uninstall and re-install it to get those fonts again. See https://askubuntu.com/a/463760/652

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see the font packages that are installed in a default install of the Ubuntu desktop, you can look at the dependencies of the meta package of your desktop, by default `ubuntu-desktop`, or `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`:

```
apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep fonts-
  Depends: fonts-dejavu-core
  Depends: fonts-freefont-ttf
  Recommends: fonts-indic
  Recommends: fonts-kacst-one
  Recommends: fonts-khmeros-core
  Recommends: fonts-lao
  Recommends: fonts-liberation
  Recommends: fonts-liberation2
  Recommends: fonts-lklug-sinhala
  Recommends: fonts-noto-cjk
  Recommends: fonts-noto-color-emoji
  Recommends: fonts-opensymbol
  Recommends: fonts-sil-abyssinica
  Recommends: fonts-sil-padauk
  Recommends: fonts-thai-tlwg
  Recommends: fonts-tibetan-machine
  Recommends: fonts-ubuntu
```

Dependencies are considered core essential fonts for the desktop environment, whereas recommended packages are advised but optional. Ubuntu is configured to, by default, install also the recommended packages.

The command

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

could automatically reinstall any of these fonts you deleted, but it would also install any other default package you may have removed.